# How to change transform.position.x after a state is changed?

Tags: unity, unityscript

When I press attack button, player will change to Normal Attack state to perform Normal Attack animation and you will notice the player seem like step back a little bit as the width of sprite for Normal Attack animation is longer than Idle animation.

http://youtu.be/hnPXt-kprqQ

To solve this issue. I need to change the `transform.position.x =+ 0.5` to move a bit further to match the position of Idle animation stands and `transform.position.x =- 0.5` when Normal Attack state done its animation and back to Idle state.

How can I perform `transform.position.x =- 0.5` when when Normal Attack state done its animation and back to Idle state?

Answer (score 1):

Unity won't allow you change a transforms components individually. You can create a new transform and initialize it accordingly, then assign it to game object.

```
Vector3 pos = transform.position;
Vector3 tmp(pos.x+0.5, pos.y, pos.z);
transform.position = tmp;
```

Comment: You don't need the `tmp`. Just modify the components of `pos` and assign it back to `transform.position`.

Comment: Yes. It was a shorthand. I better use comments next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler yet is to use the built in [`Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) method. It allows for more complex movement, like moving relative to the camera or local space and is pretty simple to use:

```
transform.Translate(0.5, 0, 0, Space.World);
```

or

```
transform.Translate(-0.5, 0, 0, Space.World);
```